# How to define a type with unknown property name but known type?

Tags: typescript

How to define a type in TypeScript to convert such JSON:

```
"MeasureList": {
  "M17": {
    "Description": "kWh-",
    "Value": "601,7"
  },
  "M300": {
    "Description": "kWh",
    "Value": "4986892,7"
  },
  "M39": {
    "Description": "ps",
    "Value": "0"
  }
}
```

into an array of well-defined types? I can make MeasureListItem typee

```
type MeasureListItem = {
    Description: string
    Value: string
}
```

and I'd like to have something like:

```
type Result = {
    measures: MeasureListItem[]
}
```

any idea?

Comment: [`type Result = { MeasureList: { [key: string]: MeasureListItem } }`](https://tsplay.dev/wQLJnW)? This is called [*index signatures*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures). I'm sure there's at least one duplicate somewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure how the type "converts" anything but yeah, index signatures.

Comment: @jcalz uuuh sorry for the wrong definition hope I didn't hurt you